# Restore one table from gz file

Tags: mysql, linux, unix

I have mysqldump file which zipped through gzip command. This compress file size is around 200G and I want to restore one table without un-compress this gzfile. My restore table might be fall into the mid of file.

```
Table name: sysusers
file: decoco.gz
```

Comment: Can you create a mysqldump for each table individual?

Comment: not possible. Because I get this file from other client

Comment: Which programming language can you use? As an example Java and C# have GZIP related libraries to read the content of the compressed data as a stream of bytes. You can reading from such a stream and can try to find the correct `CREATE TABLE` line in it.

Comment: I have only access for Linux env and dont have skills from these languages.

Comment: You can use `gunzip` or other related commands to get the content without extracting the whole file itself. See questions like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474167/gunzip-on-all-present-files-safety-regarding-memory on the different stackexchange.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score -1):

`zcat` would work:

```
zcat decoco.gz | awk '/CREATE.*TABLE.*sysusers/,/^)/' > sysusers.sql
```

Comment: Its speed is too slow and wants to find only this table script  `sysusers`  (please note this sign also  `) but its also giving some other tables also.